# VBA: Copying a cell range to different workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am currently working on an integrated set of workbooks, where I need to transfer data values between workbooks. In order to do so I need a VBA Macro that can copy a specific range (a row in a worksheet) and insert it at the bottom of an overview list in a different book.

How can I do this?

I am somewhat of a VBA novice, so specific instructions are appreciated.
Note: I'm using MS Excel 2010.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Don't you mind sharing with us at least a relevant piece of your efforts - just in support of [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) For your task try to use macro-recorder and then slightly modify code. There are plenty of similar questions here)

Answer (score 0):

The following example copy will copy the contents of the cells `A1:A3` from a `Worksheet` named `Source` in a `Workbook` named `workbook1.xlsx` into the `Worksheet` named `Target` in a different `Workbook`, `workbook1.xlsx`. It will throw an error if either of the two `Workbook`s are not open, or if they do not contain the `Worksheet`s that the `Sub` calls for.

```
Sub Example()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("workbook1.xlsx")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Source")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Target")

    ws2.Range("A1:A3") = ws1.Range("A1:A3").Value

End Sub
```